# How to add an event on long press empty view

Tags: java, android, events, insert, calendar

I am using the library by Alam Kanak accessible at this github link https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View/tree/master
For the function "onEmptyViewLongPress" I would like the user to be able to create, delete, and edit the event by long pressing an empty time slot in the calendar.

I intended that "onEmptyViewLongPress" a new intent is created and the user can enter title, begin time, and end time of the event. Following is the code I have written for enabling the user to long press and insert an event in the calendar but when I long press the app crashes. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
@Override
    public void onEmptyViewLongPress(Calendar time) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
              .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
              .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Event title")
              .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, "begin time")
              .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,"end time");
      startActivity(intent);
  }
```

Comment: If there is an obvious crash case, it's always preferred to add a crash log